# J2ME and WebBrwoser control

Tags: java-me, browser, opera-mini

How do i use the `default internet browser of cellphone` in my `J2ME` program? is it possible? or is there any developer version of `Opera Mini` for this case?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can load a page using the default browser, just use [`MIDlet.platformRequest(url)`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/midlet/MIDlet.html#platformRequest%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I want to load a page in my own interactive canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Hi Check this [PocketLearn J2ME HTML Component](http://www.j2mehtml.com/j2mehtml/) this is a 100% Java/J2ME solution for rendering HTML on MIDP 2.0 devices such as cell phones and Personal Digital Assistants. Thanks

Comment: Thank you , but it doesn't support these :
    HTML frames
    CSS (style sheets) - only supports inline styles
    HTML forms
    Scripting support (i.e. - Javascript)
    Java applets or ActiveX objects
    Flash animation
    Animated GIFs
    Support for DOM (Document Object Model)

Comment: Is there any other component?